# Has b2DebugDraw and b2ContactListener been replaced in liquidfun.js?

Tags: javascript, box2d, physics-engine, box2dweb, liquidfun

I'm trying to replace my current Box2D library (*box2dweb.js*) with **Google's LiquidFun** library.

The major difference seems like they placed all the **b2#ClassName#** classes in the global scope instead of keeping them modular (in a `Box2D.*` namespace like *box2dweb* did).

BUT it also seems like they've omitted a few **b2#ClassName#**, two of which I was using from the Box2dWeb.js version:

- **b2DebugDraw**, and;
- **b2ContactListener**;

Are those deprecated / not fully implemented / forgotten?

Comment: Regarding b2DebugDraw, I'm starting to think it's left to us to implement (based on [this](https://github.com/google/liquidfun/blob/4c49f1b3b17ce40fa1a29671789ba580897a0926/liquidfun/Box2D/Box2D/Documentation/Programmers-Guide/Chapter13_Debug_Drawing.md)). But the documentation makes no mention of b2ContactListener being deprecated (at least that I could find). If you have any more clues, please share, as I am trying to solve the same mystery.

Comment: I (finally) added the newly created tag to your question, and removed the frameworks tag, which seemed least relevant.

Comment: @Magnilex - Excellent! It's never too late :) thanks a bunch for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the listener as an object of functions, like so:

```
var listener =  {
    BeginContactBody: function(contact) {
      console.log(contact.GetFixtureA());
    },
    EndContactBody: function(contact) {
        console.log(contact.GetFixtureA());
    },
    PostSolve: function(contact, impulse) {

    },
    PreSolve: function(contact, oldManifold) {

    }
}
world.SetContactListener(listener);
```

looking at https://github.com/google/liquidfun/blob/master/liquidfun/Box2D/lfjs/jsBindings/Dynamics/b2World.js helped me solve this, so if you run into other c++ -> javascript translation issues, that's a good starting point.